# Key listener written in Java JNA. Cannot stop the thread

Tags: java, jna

I use the following code to listen to global key events:

Win32HookManager.java

```
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HMODULE;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.LRESULT;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.WPARAM;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.HHOOK;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.LowLevelKeyboardProc;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.MSG;


import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Win32HookManager {
    private static HHOOK keyboardHook;

    public static boolean installKeyboardHook(final NativeKeyboardListener listener) {
        final User32  lib  = User32.INSTANCE;
        final HMODULE hMod = Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetModuleHandle(null);

        final LowLevelKeyboardProc keyboardHookProc = new LowLevelKeyboardProc() {
            @Override
            public LRESULT callback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT info) {
                NativeKeyboardEvent ev = null;
                long                ti = System.currentTimeMillis();
                boolean             nh = true;

                if (nCode >= 0) {
                    switch (wParam.intValue()) {
                        case WinUser.WM_KEYDOWN:
                        case WinUser.WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
                            ev = new NativeKeyboardEvent(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, ti, 0, info.vkCode);
                            nh = listener.keyPressed(ev);
                            break;

                        case WinUser.WM_KEYUP:
                        case WinUser.WM_SYSKEYUP:
                            ev = new NativeKeyboardEvent(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, ti, 0, info.vkCode);
                            nh = listener.keyReleased(ev);
                            break;
                    }
                }

                if(nh) {
                    return lib.CallNextHookEx(keyboardHook, nCode, wParam, info.getPointer());
                }
                return new LRESULT(1);
            }
        };

        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                keyboardHook = lib.SetWindowsHookEx(WinUser.WH_KEYBOARD_LL, keyboardHookProc, hMod, 0);
                msgLoop();
                lib.UnhookWindowsHookEx(keyboardHook);
            }
        }.start();

        return keyboardHook != null;
    }

    public static boolean uninstallKeyboardHook() {
        if(keyboardHook != null) {
            return User32.INSTANCE.UnhookWindowsHookEx(keyboardHook);
        }

        return false;
    }

    private static void msgLoop()
    {
        final User32 lib = User32.INSTANCE;

        int result;
        MSG msg = new MSG();
        while ((result = lib.GetMessage(msg, null, 0, 0)) != 0) {
            if (result == -1) {
                System.err.println("error in get message");
                break;
            }
            else {
                System.err.println("got message");
                lib.TranslateMessage(msg);
                lib.DispatchMessage(msg);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

NativeKeyboardListener

```
public interface NativeKeyboardListener {
    public boolean keyPressed (NativeKeyboardEvent e);
    public boolean keyReleased(NativeKeyboardEvent e);
}
```

NativeKeyboardEvent

```
public class NativeKeyboardEvent {
    private int  id;
    private int  keyCode;

    public NativeKeyboardEvent(int id, long when, int modifiers, int keyCode) {
        this.id        = id;
        this.keyCode   = keyCode;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getKeyCode() {
        return keyCode;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work as I expected, i.e. it detects when a key is pressed/released, but it cannot finish the thread started by installKeyboardHook() method because of GetMessage() in msgLoop method. Yes, I can stop listening to key events, but I cannot stop the thread. However, it seems that GetMessage() is needed in this code. Do you see any workaround for this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @SLaks suggests, you need some sort of flag to indicate whether or not the message loop should continue to run. You can then use [`PeekMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644943%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ([JNA Doc](http://twall.github.com/jna/3.3.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/User32.html#PeekMessage%28com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.MSG,%20com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)) which, like `GetMessage`, retrieves a message from the queue, but is not a blocking operation. Your message loop should then be changed to something like this:

```
while (!shouldQuit) {
    while ((result = lib.PeekMessage(msg, null, 0, 0, 1)) != 0) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make a `private boolean shouldQuit` flag, and, if the flag is true, break out of the message loop.

Then, to stop the thread, just set that flag to true.

Comment: It won't work. Without GetMessage the method doesn't notify about key events. And it is thread blocking.

Comment: @user389658: You misunderstood my answer.  Use a flag field to terminate the loop when you want to.  `if (shouldQuit) break;`

Answer (score 0):

Don't install/uninstall in your message handling thread.

Only the `GetMessage` handling (and exit checking) needs to happen in the additional `Thread` (which should be a daemon thread, BTW).  Installing and removing the hook should happen elsewhere.

Look at the contributed [keyboard hook](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/contrib/w32keyhook/com/sun/jna/contrib/demo/KeyHook.java) in JNA for examples of properly procedure.

Comment: Link is dead. New location : https://github.com/thepaul/libjna-java/blob/master/contrib/w32keyhook/KeyHook.java